# Backbone.js - event trigger not work after rendering other views

Tags: events, view, backbone.js, triggers, render

There's a `addPost` function in my router. I don't want to re-create the `postAddView` every time the function is invoked:

```
addPost: function () {
  var that = this;
  if (!this.postAddView) {
    this.postAddView = new PostAddView({
      model: new Post()
    });
    this.postAddView.on('back', function () {
      that.navigate('#/post/list', { trigger: true });
    });
  }

  this.elms['page-content'].html(this.postAddView.render().el);
}
```

Here's the PostAddView:

```
PostAddView = backbone.View.extend({
  events: {
    'click #post-add-back': 'back'
  }
  , back: function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.trigger('back');
  }
});
```

The first time the postAddView is rendered, the event trigger works well. However, after rendering other views to `page-content` and render `postAddView` back, the event trigger won't be trigger anymore. The following version of `addPost` works well, though.

```
addPost: function () {
  var that = this, view;

  view = new PostAddView({
    model: new Post()
  });

  this.elms['page-content'].html(view.render().el);

  view.on('back', function () {
    delete view;
    that.navigate('#/post/list', { trigger: true });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somewhere you are calling jQuery's [`remove`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) and that

> In addition to the elements themselves, all bound events and jQuery data associated with the elements are removed.

so the [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) call that Backbone uses to bind events to your `postAddView.el` will be lost. Then, when you re-add your `postAddView.el`, there are is no `delegate` attached anymore and no events are triggered. Note that Backbone.View's standard [`remove`](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#View-remove) method calls jQuery's `remove`; a few other things in jQuery, just as [`empty`](http://api.jquery.com/empty/) will do similar things to event handlers. So the actual function call that is killing your `delegate` could be hidden deep inside something else.

You could try calling [`delegateEvents`](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#View-delegateEvents) manually:

```
this.elms['page-content'].html(this.postAddView.render().el);
this.postAddView.delegateEvents();
```

or better, just throw the view away and create a new one every time you need it. Your view objects should be pretty light weight so creating new ones should be cheap and a lot less hassle than trying to keep track of the existing views by hand.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to reuse the current DOM and View you do not need to set again and again the element as you are doing, everything that you call `.html()` you are destroying the DOM of the View and generating again and losing events. Also I prefer always to add the "el" in the DOM before render the View. I will have your function in this way:

```
addPost: function () {
  if (!this.postAddView) {
    this.postAddView = new PostAddView({
      model: new Post()
    });
    this.postAddView.on('back', this.onBack);
    this.elms['page-content'].html(this.postAddView.el);
  }

  this.postAddView.render();

},

onBack : function () {
  this.navigate('#/post/list', { trigger: true });
}
```

I'm not fan of the use of local variables to refer to "this". If all of your Views uses `_.bindAll(this)` in the initialize method you could bind your events to your view and could use this(check how I transformed onBack).

With my code there is not a need to manually call `this.delegateEvents()`